# Python - ObjectListView Filter

Tags: python, filter, wxpython, objectlistview, objectlistview-python

I have read [here](http://objectlistview-python-edition.readthedocs.org/en/latest/features.html?highlight=filter#filtering) and  I'm trying to filter ObjectListView by using `Filter.Predicate(booleanCallable)` as follows:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self,name,author,length):
        self.name=name
        self.author=author
        self.length=str(length)


class ObjectDataView(ObjectListView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ObjectListView.__init__(self, parent, size=(400,400), pos=(0,0), style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        self.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Name", "left", 400/3, "name"),
            ColumnDefn("Author", "left", 400/3, "author"),
            ColumnDefn("Length", "left", 400/3, "length"),

        ])

    def filter_view(self):
        self.SetFilter(Filter.Predicate(self.filter_me))
        self.Update()

    def filter_me(self,obj):
        return obj.length == '10'


app=wx.App()
frame=wx.Frame(None,-1,"Check",size=(400,400))
panel=wx.Panel(frame,size=frame.GetSize())

view = ObjectDataView(panel)
view.AddObject(Book("hary1","ori",10))
view.AddObject(Book("hary2","ori",10))
view.AddObject(Book("hary3","s",15))
view.AddObject(Book("hary4","s",15))
view.AddObject(Book("hary5","s",15))

view.filter_view()
frame.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

But when I call `filter_view()` it doesn't do anything.. I use ObjectListView because one of it's features is the buitin Filter. I also tried using `self.SetFilter(self.filter_me)` but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your filter_view to:

```
def filter_view(self):
    self.SetFilter(olv.Filter.Predicate(self.filter_me))
    self.RepopulateList()
```

see: ObjectListView.SetFilter

Comment: the `self.RepopulateList()` fixed it.. Thank you!